# Snap.svg Limited Viewport

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Found out about Snap.svg very recently. Was following a tutorial on YouTube to the letter. For some reason my viewport is incredibly limited. Does anyone know why this is happening? Chrome is my browser so I doubt that's the issue.

```js
var s = Snap('#svg')
var myCircle = s.circle(150,150,100)
myCircle.attr({
  fill:'#f00',
  stroke:'#000',
  strokeWidth:2
});
var aLoop = function(r){
  var newR = r===50 ? 100 : 50
  myCircle.animate({r:r}, 1500, function () {
    aLoop(newR)
  })
}

myCircle.drag()
aLoop(50)
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>snap.svg</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg id="svg"></svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyway, let me know what you guys think. The goal would be to be able to move the animated Circle throughout the entire browser window. Thanks :)

Comment: I edited your post (to fix the indentation), and realise that you forgot the body. Doesn't matter at all for your problem, just a remark.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the size of the drawing in CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Or if you want easily the whole window

```
#svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is adding a drawing area a necessary part of using Snap.svg? YouTube tut said nothing about this. Would much rather have the whole Window as a default drawing area. Thanks though, step in the right direction.

Comment: The "drawing area" is what you define with `var s = Snap('#svg')`. So the size with depend of the size of  `div#svg`. Also, try `s.rect('100%', '100%')`

Comment: Woops, don't try `s.rect()` it's for `svg.js`.

Comment: I edited my answer. Actually you just have to set the size in CSS